# Issue with Stack Overflow site: It keeps logging me out

Tags: bug, logout

After logging into Stack Overflow, after sometime it logs me out. I am experiencing this problem from today morning.

Comment: And I do not give to ask questions :)

Comment: It would be helpful to know your browser and version.

Comment: IE 8.0. This was happening since today morning only.

Comment: It seems things are woring fine since reporting this problem till now. So can somebody tell me how to close this issue?